# Apply a condition to every column in a dataframe except a list of some string columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply the following calculation in all the columns of a dataframe EXCEPT a list of 3 string columns. The issue is that although the code bellow works fine based on the sample data, in reality the Month columns are upwards of 100+ and they are getting increased every month while the 3 string columns are fix. The months list should contain 100+ columns which they will be +1 every month so I want to just apply the /100 on all the columns that the View description == 'Percent change' except the Series ID, View Description and Country columns. How can I modify the list so that it includes just the 3 string columns and the .loc is applied to everything else.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Series ID': ['Food', 'Drinks', 'Food at Home'],
    'View Description': ['Percent change', 'Original Data Value', 'Original Data Value'],
    'Jan': [219.98, 'B', 'A'],
    'Feb': [210.98, 'B', 'A'],
    'Mar': [205, 'B', 'A'],
    'Apr': [202, 'B', 'A'],
    'Country': ['Italy', 'B', 'A']
})

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
df.loc[df['View Description'] == 'Percent change', months] /= 100
print(df)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `months` to be a boolean array which omits the string columns:

```
months = ~df.columns.isin(['Series ID', 'View Description', 'Country'])
```

The command for applying the division will be the same as you have above.  This change just programmatically selects the month columns by excluding the non-month columns.